# Collect notifications in a submenu such as Windows

Tags: window, notification, system-tray, taskbar, notification-area

[windows notification area](https://i.stack.imgur.com/giprq.png)

Hello
I am trying to make application icons appear in sub menu like Windows (with Dash-To-Panel extension)

How can I do this? There is any extension can do That?

**Edit:**

Operating System: Ubuntu Desktop (20.04)

white gnome extentions: Dash To Panel, Ark Menu

Comment: To start with, which version of Linux have you installed  (Ubuntu server, Ubuntu desktop, Kubuntu, Lubuntu, Xubuntu, Ubuntu MATE, et al.) , and which release number?  Different releases have different tools for us to recommend. Please click [edit] and add that vital information to your question so all the facts we need are in the question. Please don't use Add Comment, since that's our channel to you. All facts about your system should go in the Question with [edit]

Answer (score 0):

The GNOME Shell extension [Dash-to-Panel](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1160/dash-to-panel/) seems to do what you want.

There are [over 1,200 extensions available](https://extensions.gnome.org/) for your review. You can enter the word *panel* in the search box which will narrow them down to only about 200 extensions. The [GNOME Tweak Tool](https://wiki.gnome.org/action/show/Apps/Tweaks?action=show&redirect=Apps%2FGnomeTweakTool) also allows [changing Panel options](https://itsfoss.com/gnome-tweak-tool/).